# Function return `undefined` in JS odoo 10

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I have tried below code, but getting `undefined`.

```
init: function(parent){
    var value = this.read_data();
    console.log('value',value);//Prints undefined
}

read_data: function() {
    my_model.query(["name"]).all().then(function(data){
        console.log('dataa',data);//Here print value
        return data[0].name
    });
},
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Your `read_data` function is asynchronous, it calls a function that does not immediately return something but will only do that after a while. As such you cannot just return the value from your `read_data` function simply because it isn’t there yet by the time the function completes. In addition, you actually do not return anything from the `read_data` function itself.

You call `my_model.query(["name"]).all()` which apparently returns a Promise, an asynchronous task. On completion of that task (`.then(…)`), you call a function which logs out the data and returns a value.

So far so good, this makes the whole thing return a promise itself, a promise for the value `data[0].name` once the query is done. However, that promise is never returned, so you have no way of knowing when that happens.

To fix that, simply return the whole thing from `read_data`:

```
read_data: function() {
// return the resulting promise here
//  ↓↓↓↓↓↓
    return my_model.query(["name"]).all().then(function(data){
        console.log('dataa',data);//Here print value
        return data[0].name
    });
}
```

This makes `read_data` properly asynchronous itself and makes it return a promise for the result. So now you can consume that promise in your `init` function:

```
init: function(parent){
    this.read_data().then(function (value) {
        console.log('value', value);
    });
}
```

Since `read_data()` returns a promise, we have to await its result and can only act once the promise is resolved. To do that, we use `.then(…)` again to do something after the promise is fulfilled.